# Determine if python string is comprised of only combination of blank spaces, tabs, and/or new lines?

Tags: python, performance, character

If I have a string, `foo`, and I'm curious if it is comprised of only a combination of blank spaces , tabs `\t`, and `\n` newline characters (could be any amount of any of them, but only them), what is an efficient way to check for that?

My instinct was to to convert `foo` to a set, `set(foo)`, and see if that set is only made up of a combination of those characters.  While I can envision some iterative checks, wondering what an efficient approach would be.  This check would be per element in an XML document, thousands of times in a pyspark map function, so performance is important.

Thanks.

Comment: `not foo.strip()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bahrom's suggestion in the comments would work, but the fastest way might be to use a regular expression. Compile a regex that searches for things that *aren't* spaces:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"[^ \t\n]")
```

Then run it on every `foo`:

```
is_all_spaces = re.search(pattern, foo) is None
```

This should be plenty fast, but remember to always measure. (The `timeit` module may useful.) In particular, measure whether this checking-for-whitespace part of your code takes any significant amount of time compared to, say, the XML parsing part.

<sup>Why the double negative, you ask? Looking for things that aren't spaces, instead of just writing a regex that matches a bunch of spaces (`r"^[ \t\n]*$"`), means that we're not creating and destroying a match object if the string is all spaces. If that's the most common case, it could be slightly faster. How much faster? I couldn't tell you - I haven't measured it.</sup>

Comment: Appreciate the answer and thoughts.  While originally I thought the .strip() from @Bahrom's answer might be more readable, that obfuscates what characters are being stripped.  This regex approach is a bit more explicit, which I like.  Thanks!